# Connect "Speech to Text" with the Input Type text

Tags: html, css

I have built a code for "speech to text" and of course I've created an input type text BUT when I speak (to my computer) the words don't go into the input type text. Why? I want the word "Hello" into this bar! For example check the photo below:

[image]

Comment: share your `html` and `js` which sets the `innerHTML` values to the `<label>` or `<input>`.

Comment: Thanks mate for answering but still did't find it... hahahahah. Listen, I think the problem is that I put <p id="p"></p> and after I use the input. I think I must delete this paragraph and to put it into the input! Or not?

Comment: If you figured it out, good for you.

Comment: Could you please show the code? By the way, Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also see how to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware how you do it - but this works fine

It uses Web Speech Api's SpeechRecognition (refer)->https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

**Also please understand its cross browser compatibility(works in chrome)** - *no support for firefox i believe* -> please try and verify

It has a grammar list of colors when said the data is input into the input type text field (you might have another list or may be not have it at all)

*example is from the link mentioned above*

```js
var color = "aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghostwhite | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow";
var colorArray = color.split(" | ");
for (i = 0; i <= colorArray.length; i++) {
  $("ul").append("<li>" + colorArray[i] + "</li>");
}
var SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = ' + color + ";";
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new webkitSpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

var bg = document.querySelector('html');

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Ready to receive a color command.');
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var color = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  $("input").val(color);
  bg.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="output">Click Here to speak</h1>

<input type="text">
<br>
<h4>List of colors</h4>
<ul>

</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**The code might not work here** -> please run it from an environment other than this *(needs allow microphone permission)*

Hope it is useful

Comment: Hello my bro! I just uploaded a photo of my whole code. Please, it's very stupid my problem but I cannot find it! Thanks